# ASP.NET MVC 2 Data Collection on Site.Master Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a site.master page in which I need to collect a newsletter signup, so I would prefer if I can provide feedback immediately to the user as they signup, and not disrupt any other page activities.  It is a simple textbox and button.

The data then gets written to a remote WCF web service, so could I use an AJAX call, although that would be cross domain, which might be an issue.  The service returns a message of success or why failed.

So, my questions are, what would be the best approach for this implementation, and can I use the service?

Thanks!
Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid the cross-domain problem, I would use the "double hop" solution. First, add a reference to the WCF service in your project. Then create a method in your Controller that returns a `JsonResult`, and inside that method you can call the WCF service and return the result as JSON.

Then in the client app you can use a standard `.ajax()` method to do the sign-up. It's a little convoluted with the number of hops, but it lets you control each step of the process and avoids the cross-domain problem.

Comment: Hi Mgnoonan, I was coming to that conclusion; probably will go that route.  Thanks for your help!